# How to debug when I add event listener to a button

Tags: javascript, console, addeventlistener

I would like to create a simple login, which asks the user to enter username and pin. In the meantime I wanted to check with debug console whether I did mistake. But as soon as I click the button, I see in console the logs but it goes away as quick as a flash. Why doesn't it stay? What can I do in order the console to stay?

```js
const account1 = {
  owner: 'Jonas Schmedtmann',
  movements: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],
  interestRate: 1.2, // %
  pin: 1111,
};

const account2 = {
  owner: 'Jessica Davis',
  movements: [5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30],
  interestRate: 1.5,
  pin: 2222,
};

const account3 = {
  owner: 'Steven Thomas Williams',
  movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460],
  interestRate: 0.7,
  pin: 3333,
};

const account4 = {
  owner: 'Sarah Smith',
  movements: [430, 1000, 700, 50, 90],
  interestRate: 1,
  pin: 4444,
};

const accounts = [account1, account2, account3, account4];

//we create a username for each account

//to create a username for each account, we need to call the userName() function one time.
userName(accounts);
const btnLogin = document.querySelector('.login__btn');

btnLogin.addEventListener('click',function(){
  const user = inputLoginUsername.value;
  const pin = inputLoginPin.value;
  const acc = accounts.find((account,i,arr)=>account.username===user);

  if(acc){
    console.log('account found');
  }else{
    console.log('account not found');
    }  
});
```

```html
<form class="login">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="user"
          class="login__input login__input--user"
        />
        <!-- In practice, use type="password" -->
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="PIN"
          maxlength="4"
          class="login__input login__input--pin"
        />
        <button class="login__btn">&rarr;</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Enable the option to not clear the console on navigation.

Comment: But I suspect what you actually want is to listen for the `submit` event and call `.preventDefault()` so that you don't submit the form to the server when clicking that button.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the Browser **Dev Tools** when running the above code, it gives the reason why it isn't working

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: inputLoginUsername is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (js:29)
```

You should probably use `getElementById` to get the field your interested in. You also referenced an `accounts` object that doesn't exist.

Here is the code printing the value of the `user` and `pin`, with `account` removed as I don't know what it is, other than an array of objects.

```js
const btnLogin = document.querySelector('.login__btn');

btnLogin.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const user = document.getElementById('user').value;
  const pin = document.getElementById('pin').value;
  console.log(user);
  console.log(pin);
});
```

```html
<form class="login">
        <input
          id="user"
          type="text"
          placeholder="user"
          class="login__input login__input--user"
        />
        <!-- In practice, use type="password" -->
        <input
          id="pin"
          type="text"
          placeholder="PIN"
          maxlength="4"
          class="login__input login__input--pin"
        />
        <button class="login__btn">&rarr;</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: just added event.preventDefault(); it worked well for me thank you. I have updated the code. There is an array named accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
let form = document.getElementsByClassName("login");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome, and surely others browser, in the developer window (where there is Inspector, Console, etc.), you have a "Source" tab. There, you can put some breakpoints. Check [this website](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) for Google Chrome and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Outils/D%C3%A9bogueur/Comment/Ajouter_un_point_d_arr%C3%AAt) for Mozilla Firefox.

Thus, you can stop the execution of your code before the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

type debugger; in your code from where you want to start debugging and make sure in browser's developer tool you have enabled debugging.

```
debugger;
```

check this link for reference.